# Webcam Focus and exposure control using Command Line (or PHP)

Tags: php, powershell, cmd

I am currently developing a photobooth app using Laravel, and this app is hosted on my machine itself, so there is no problem in the command line control access (and atm, there are some functions using `exec()` ). The webcam is connected to the machine.

For the above purpose, I want to be able to control the focus and exposure values of my webcam while in the command line so as to be able to calibrate the camera before setting up the photo booth.

I looked into some of the possible options with regard to this, and because I am currently deploying this on a Windows 10 Machine, all I could find was that there is no simple way to approach this problem, other than to create a C++ executable to access the Drivers, which, based on my skill level, would take a longer time than allocated.

Therefore, I would like to know the following:

1. What command line tool I can use for this purpose.
2. If there is no such tool, an alternative approach I could follow.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look to the Users Guide of your Webcam, if it has such a functionality and how it's done. If you share that information, we might be able to help you "translate" the needed commands.

Comment: Hi @Stephan I currently use Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920. However, I could not find any way to control this through the user guides I have currently.

Comment: To control anything from command line, you'd need a command line utility for the camera. I didn't find one (and I very much doubt there is one) or the specifications of the interface/driver to write one of your own (but I very much doubt, any Vendor will share this kind of data). You might want to ask for help [at the Logitech Community](http://support.logitech.com/de_de/product/hd-pro-webcam-c920/forums)